# Decision point for the user in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs, decision-tree

Test is waiting while page will load text: 'SomeText', which is working fine.
However now on the other hand when page won't find the text user should be able to decide whether to continue with testing or not.

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper.waitForText("SomeText", function() {
    this.echo('Found the result :)');
}, function(){
    casper.echo('Result not found! :( Would you like to continue testing? (Y/N)');
    ...
   }, 15000);
});
```

I found many general answers, but nothing for Casper/Phantom

Comment: CasperJS can easily wait for arbitrary events or data, but how do you propose to get input from the user? It's not possible to run CasperJS in the interactive PhantomJS (REPL) mode.